Why replit console doesnt sees my new file?
Hello I just deleted old file name is "main.rb" then i created new on on new folder named "ruby.rb" to test ruby but the problem is console still sees the deleted one what i am supposed to do.
enter image description here
i tried to change the entrypoint from .replit file to "ruby.rb" but it still doesnt work i shared my problem to screenshot i even asked gpt i tried to instruction which it gives but still not working

Go to the .replit file.
It looks like this by default:
run = "bundle exec ruby main.rb"
hidden = [".bundle"]
entrypoint = "main.rb"
modules = ["ruby-3.2:v6-20240209-9e3a339"]

[nix]
channel = "stable-23_11"

[gitHubImport]
requiredFiles = [".replit", "replit.nix"]

You just need to change the run command to
run = "bundle exec ruby ruby.rb"

While I am not certain what the "entrypoint" does you should probably change this as well simply because it references a nonexistent file.
